# mkfifo под windows

Tags: c++, linux

Есть задачка: собрать некий проект под виндами. В нём подключается линуховая ф-я mkfifo. 
Вроде-как есть её описание в *MS Windows Services for UNIX*. Но так все статические библиотеки *.so! Что делать, в какую сторону копать вообще? Или легче переписать на Win PIPE?

Comment: MS Windows Services for UNIX - это SFU (Interix)?  

А сейчас она работает? У меня последний раз с ней получилось в SP2 (в SP3 она работать отказалась (не помню уже почему) а в 7 не пробовал).   

@Afftobus, если это она и она работает, сообщите **пожалуйста**.

Comment: Я под sp2 юзаю. И то не понял, как на этом собирать и что это такое, портирование из линукса в виндовс или наоборот. 

Расскажите, плиз, что там делать нужно?
ЗЫ вроде, да, это она.

Comment: Из Linux (вообще-то SFU на основе bsd) в Windows. Просто собираете исходники на Си в ней (gcc) и в основном все работало. Плюс юниксовые команды, шелл и т.п. 

Мне **очень** нравилась...

Comment: У меня проект для студии. Хочет mkfifo. В хедерах-то он есть, а как к виндовому проекту *.so подключать?
Или тут нужно makefile`ы использовать?

Comment: Ну ясно же что студия не будет работать с gcc. Надо использовать либо руками, либо makefile'ом.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать собрать в dev-c++, там используется Cygwin, позволяющий собирать для вин никсовый код.

Comment: dev-c++ линуксовым собирать?

Comment: Уже Sygwin'ы какие-то появились? В cygwin (www.cygwin.com) вроде mkfifo была. Использует скорее всего виндовые именованные трубы. Но если беспокоит гондурас с лицензированием, то надо учитывать, что cygwin1.dll -- она под GPLv3+. А так при разработке пакета старались обеспечивать совместимость с linux больше, чем совместимость с posix.
Собирать под него можно и под линуксом, но ценой дополнительных телодвижений (установки пакетов). Под cygwin'ом проще.

Comment: Cygwin, конечно, не ту клавишу ткнул.